# BeautifulSoup does not work properly on server

Tags: python, http, backend, unicorn, fastapi

I have developed my backend using FastApi, and I am running it with the Unicorn on AWS EC2 ubuntu. In my code, I use  BeautifulSoup to work on XML files, but when I pass the large XML file with an HTTP request, it does not work properly and returns the only first line of the XML document. When I try it locally on windows, and I send an HTTP request to my local machine it is fine. How could I solve it? Is it because of http timeout?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. How large is the failing input? Are there any error/log messages?

Comment: @ggorlen File is 7mb with 90k lines of XML. There is not any error, I printed the BeautifulSoap input string I can see the complete xml, but output of beautifulsoup is only first line of xml, but it is not a case in my local machine. In small files everything is fine.

Comment: All right, I'm not sure what to suggest, but requests and BS are totally different things. BS is an HTML parser and has no concept of HTTP timeouts, so if the route has a timeout and you're making a request that the server can't fulfill because it's blocked for a long time as BS is parsing HTML, there's the problem relative to running it locally without a request timeout. All of this is purely speculation.

Comment: @ggorlen I also thought that it is http timeout but it is not, it is vary interesting for me, I am not sure if there is any difference between linux and windows machine for such a task.